# TensorFlow CondaVerificationError - Mixing Pip with Conda

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, pip, conda

I'm running Anaconda 64 bit on Windows 10 and I've encountered a CondaVerificationError when I try installing TensorFlow 2.0 on one of my computers. I believe the error stems from mixing pip installations with conda installations for the same package. I originally installed then uninstalled TensorFlow with pip and then tried installing with conda and now I'm stuck trying to resolve this issue.
    I've tried reinstalling Anaconda but the issue persists. Thoughts?

Comment: Did you just reinstall or did you uninstall+delete all folders associated with anaconda and then reinstall?

Comment: I deleted the envs and pkgs packages inside the anaconda folder before running the Anaconda uninstaller. Should I delete all python projects as well if they contain a __pycache__ folder as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

I reinstalled TensorFlow 2.0 with pip and even though it successfully installed, I was still facing issues when I tried to run my code. A file called cudart64_100.dll could not be located. I eventually managed to get my TF 2.0 code to run successfully by installing an older version of CUDA. I'm still not sure what the issue is with conda, but I'll settle for the current working version of anaconda.